# QlikView: Insert and update based on condition (without timestamp)

Tags: qlikview

I have encountered a problem when I am trying to write a script to one version of `Insert and Update` Incremental Load.

**Example:** To simplify the example I have made an illustration of how I want the data-set to update. (I leave the code for the discussion)

**Illustration:** [image: Illustration of the Insert and Update]

In the example above, you can see that I both want insert new records and to update records. The condition is that I only want to update records if the new value is greater than the existing record.

For instance, the existing record for ID 2 equals to 0 (Table 1) and since the new record for ID 2 equals to 100 (Table 2) I want to Update that record so the final updated record for ID 2 equals to the highest value of them two (Updated Table). If Table 2 contains a new record I just want to add that record to the final data-set.

**Description:**

1. Insert new records
2. Update records if the value is higher than the existing record

What do you guys think is the best solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's the best solution

```
//QVD
Table:
LOAD * INLINE [
ID, Value, Source
1, 500, 'QVD'
2, 0, 'QVD'
3, 100, 'QVD'
4, 300, 'QVD'
5, 0, 'QVD'
];

//ODBC
Concatenate(Table)
LOAD * INLINE [
ID, Value, Source
2, 100, ODBC
3, 700, ODBC
4, 300, ODBC
6, 500, ODBC
7, 0, ODBC
];

NewTable:
LOAD
    ID,
    max(Value) as Value
Resident Table
Group by ID
;

drop Table Table;
```